# JS FlexSlider doesn't work in Joomla 3

Tags: javascript, joomla, flexslider

I have a JS FlexSlider module in my joomla page.
It works fine on all positions but not at the Position I want it to be.

And the position works fine with all other modules.

Here is the page: http://www.ehemalige-hoelderlingym.de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your browser console, you will see a JS error. You also have 2 jQuery libraries being imported which simply means that the developer of FlexSlider has not stuck to Joomla coding standards.

In the Module Parameters, you will see the option **Enable jQuery 1.8.2?** which you need to set to **No**.

This will prevent duplicate jQuery libraries being imported and thus most likely fix the console error.

They should really remove this option for the Joomla 3.x version of JS FlexSlider as it is simply not required.

### Update:

I've checked Firebug and you're now getting an error because the module is importing the script before jQuery.

You have 3 options:

**Option 1:** Download and install the [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) plugin. This will ensure jQuery is loaded only once and before any other script on your site.

**Option 2:** Create a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the module and once done, in the default.php change this:

```
<script src="modules/mod_js_flexslider/assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to this:

```
<?php JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_js_flexslider/assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js'); ?>
```

**Option 3:** Use a different slider extension

---

Personally I would go with option 3 as you shouldn't have to rely on a 3rd party plugin to get a slider working, and option 2 is something the developer should do.